# Optimization on List key comparisons and return value with HashMap

Tags: java, performance, hash-map

Consider this code:

```
           public class DataSt {

            DataType time;
            DataType memory;


            public DataSt(DataType time, DataType memory)
            {
                this.time=time;
                this.memory=memory;
            }

            private static void saveIt(DataSt p, DataSt p2, String keyval, List<DataSt> comp) {      
                  ...
                }


            private static void saveIt( String keyval, List<DataSt> comp) {
                     ...
         }

            public static List<DataSt> compO(List<DataSt> curR, List<DataSt> prevR) {            
                Map<String,DataSt> cur = new HashMap<>();Map<String,DataSt> prev= new HashMap<>();      
                for(DataSt abc:curR)
                {
                    DataSt v = new DataSt (abc.time,abc.memory);
                    cur.put(abc.key,v);
                }

                for(DataSt abc:prevR)
                {
                    DataSt values = new DataSt (abc.time,abc.memory);
                    prev.put(abc.key,v);
                }

                List<DataSt> comp = new ArrayList<DataSt>();

                for (Entry < String, DataSt > abc: cur.entrySet()) {
                    if (prev.containsKey(abc.getKey())) {
                        saveIt(abc.getValue(), prev.get(abc.getKey()), abc.getKey(), comp);
                    } else {
                        saveIt(abc.getKey(), comp);
                    }
                }

                for (Entry<String, DataSt> abc: prev.entrySet()) {
                    if (!(cur.containsKey(abc.getKey()))) {
                        saveIt(abc.getKey(), comp);
                    }
                }   
                return comp;
            }
        }
```

With reference to the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230104/list-key-comparisons-and-return-value". It would be great if someone could review the code and suggest optimizations.

Comment: You've added the performance tag. Do you experience any performance issues?

Comment: @t3chb0t no I don't....... just wanted to make sure I have a well optimized code w.ref. to the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230104/list-key-comparisons-and-return-value" as I need to store the final comparison result into a List where the comparison turns little hard w.r.t ArrayList as suggested in the above link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static List<DataSt> compO(List<DataSt> curR, List<DataSt> prevR) {

    Map<String,DataSt> cur = new HashMap<>();Map<String,DataSt> prev= new HashMap<>();
   curR.parallelStream().forEach(entry -> cur.put(entry.key,new DataSt (entry.time,entry.memory)));
   prevR.parallelStream().forEach(entry -> prev.put(entry.key,new DataSt (entry.time,entry.memory)));

    List<DataSt> comp = new ArrayList<DataSt>();
    for (Entry < String, DataSt > abc: cur.entrySet()) {
        final String key = abc.getKey();
        if (prev.containsKey(key)) {
            saveIt(abc.getValue(), prev.get(key), key, comp);
        } else {
            saveIt(key, comp);
        }
    }

    for (Entry<String, DataSt> abc: prev.entrySet()) {
        final String key = abc.getKey();
        if (!(cur.containsKey(key))) {
            saveIt(key, comp);
        }
    }
    return comp;
}
```

Also you can try to use parallel stream on map, but it should not be `HashMap`, and I'm not sure that it will be faster.

Comment: Please, mark this answer as right if it is true.